# C program to transfer pixels of a real time video image

Tags: c

I need to know the C program used to transfer pixels of a real time video image of size 160*120 into another table of same size using array

Comment: You want to write one or want to know some existing implementation? This question in its current form makes little sense, can you edit it and be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kBytesPerPixel 4
#define kPixelsPerRow 160
#define kRowsPerFrame 120
#define kBytesPerFrame (kRowsPerFrame*kPixelsPerRow*kBytesPerPixel)
typedef struct { unsigned char raw[kBytesPerFrame]; } VideoFrame;

*(VideoFrame *)target = *(VideoFrame *)source;
```